# Asp.net Core disable a tag in li

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

In Asp.net Core Web Application, I have an html part below in View, I want to disable one of the  tag, but I failed to mark it work.
`<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li ><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
   <li ><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
   <li ><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>`
The closest way, I found is **class="disabled"**.

```
<li class="disabled"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
```

But, the About still could be clicked.
In some similar thread which is suggest to use custom Authoring Tag Helpers, but it is not able to set the attribute by disable property. It is read-only.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in HTML, the disabled attribute is not valid for li.

Answer (score 3):

You can *disable* a link using JavaScript (`event.preventDefault()`). Instead of adding this everywhere you can create a TagHelper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "disabled-link")]
public class DisabledLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("onclick", "event.preventDefault()");
        return base.ProcessAsync(context, output);
    }
}
```

Then, don't forget to declare the tag helper in the view:

```
@addTagHelper *, WebApplication1
```

And use it:

```
<a href="test" disabled-link>Disabled</a>
```

this generate

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault()" href="test">Disabled</a>
```

Comment: well explained.